# I want to make a slider custom bottom value with incremet in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[image]

Please help me,

I want to make this type slider with the same value get by the slider value

I am facing the problem to set value the in specific divisions with the below division values like 1x 3x

Answer (score 0):

In your question you just describe what you want to do, but you don't say what problem you're facing. Please see this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to create more descriptive questions next time.

check the [Material Library / Slider Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html)

Also there are many different style example if you can search.
[some example and anatomy of slider](https://blog.logrocket.com/flutter-slider-widgets-deep-dive-with-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

More of a workaround, but this should work.

```dart
final mapper = {0:0, 1:3, 2:5, 3:10};

...

Slider(
  min: 0.0,
  max: 3.0,
  divisions: 3,
  value: _value,
  label: '${mapper[_value]}',
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _value = value;
      returnValue = mapper[_value]
    });
  },
)
```